# Openpyxl Copying Formula in Specific Column

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am attempting to pull down a formula located in cell E2 through the rest of the "E" column, but I can't quite figure out how to. My current code adds the cells in the E column to the cells in the "D" column which is not what I want.

Current Code:

```
#Copy Formulae 
pathway = glob.glob("Updated Workbook.xlsx") #Pulls filename
pathway = ''.join(pathway)
w_b = load_workbook(pathway) #Pulls workbook using filename
w_s = w_b['Sheet 1'] #Sets worksheet to pull formula through
for row, cellObj in enumerate(list(w_s.columns)[4]): #Iterates through the rows to pull formulae down through cells
    if row != 0: #Causes header row to be skipped
        n = '=(D%d*E%d)' % (row + 1, row + 1)
        cellObj.value = n
w_b.save('Copied Formulae.xlsx')
```

Comment: What is the formula that should be in `E2`. Current code is writing `=D2*E2` in `E2` and so on...

Comment: @Redox the formula is a lengthy excel formula `=IF(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE([@cBarcode]," ",""),15),1)="P",REPLACE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE([@cBarcode]," ",""),15),1,1,""),RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE([@cBarcode]," ",""),15))`

Comment: Hi - When I ran your code earlier, it ran fine. Cell `E2` had the formula `=(D2*E2)`. Other than the circular reference, it seemed to be correct. So, asked the question. This formula was 'pulled down' till there was data in D column. So I guess the question is, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Redox the formula works with `=(D2*E2)` but it doesn't seem to work with `=IF(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE([@cBarcode]," ",""),15),1)="P",REPLACE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE([@cBarcode]," ",""),15),1,1,""),RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE([@cBarcode]," ",""),15))`

Comment: You don't say how it doesn't work. Anyway you will at least need to delimit the Quotes. If the whole formula is being rejected by Excel try breaking it into sections; add and correct each section as you go.